# Trying to invoke onchange method set by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

In my code, I am setting a change listener on my checkboxes here

```
  $(".section").change(function() { 
       if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("." + this.id).show();
        ...
```

Now I am trying to do a "code-driven" click on the checkbox, and I have

```
  $(".secTitle").click(function(e) {
    var elem = this;
    while(elem) {
      if (elem.className && elem.className.indexOf ('DOC_SECTION') != -1) {
        var clzes = elem.className.split(" ");
        var clzIdx = 1;
        if (elem.getAttribute('closeSecClassIdx')) {
          clzIdx = parseInt(elem.getAttribute('closeSecClassIdx'));
        }
        var chk = document.getElementById(clzes[clzIdx]);
        chk.checked = false;
        alert(chk.onchange);
        //chk.changed();
        break;
      }
      else {
        elem = elem.parentNode;
      }
    }
  });
```

I know that I have the right element, as `chk.checked = false;` is working correctly. After that I'm trying to invoke the change method set earlier but my alert is showing 'undefined'.

Comment: jQuery does not insert anything into `onchange` when you bind a event callback to it!

Comment: You have to trigger the `change` event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the `change` event by calling `$(chk).change()`.  Below I've created a little prototype that shows binding to the `change` event and invoking it.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    // bind to the change event
    $("input").change(function() {
        console.log('change triggered!');
    });
    
    // now trigger it
    $("input").change();    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
```